# Mini-Cart displaying Configurable Product Image instead of simple Product Image Magento 2

Tags: configurable-product, mini-cart, magento-2.1.1

While adding product variations from configurable product, in mini cart it displays only configurable product image,

how to show simple product image instead of current parent image.

Comment: please let me know if you have any issue.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to do setting from admin panel.

GO to Admin panel,

> Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Shopping Cart ->
>   Configurable Product Image

Set Product Thumbnail itself from dropdown list.

Save Confiration.

Comment: For me in cart and checkout has such problem but this doesn't resolved for me M2.2X

Comment: For me (M2.2.5) this option only changes thumbnail in summary on checkout. Cart view always have child product thumbnail and minicart always have parent thumbnail.