# Issue in product image color in magento 2.2X?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, swatches, color-swatches

I have two **swatches** i.e., `red and black`

And when a user clicks `red` colour it changes the colour of the image

But in cart the image is `base image only`.

**So the issue is, Selected options image isn't updating there**

Kindly help us to get over this.

Comment: Any custom modules which overrides the cart or catalog ? Or it's fresh magento 2.2 ?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138604/mini-cart-displaying-configurable-product-image-instead-of-simple-product-image?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa followed this link but couldn't get rid of it.The issue still persist and answer to your question there is no module overriding it.

Comment: Actually the image that is taking from parent product instead of simple product image. Need to fix this asap. Kindly provide some solution.

Comment: Still the issue isn't fixed yet. @AdityaShah

Comment: just a moment giving you a solution

Comment: have you also tested this on the default Blank and/or Luma themes which come with Magento2?

Comment: php bin/magento catalog:images:resize

Comment: Can get rid of it, still... @AdityaShah

Comment: In magento 2.2.4 working fine, can you please share your version ? 2.2.x

Comment: Magento 2.2.0 not an theme issue.I will provide the url and you can check even.
URL : http://streetstrider.enterpriseapplicationdevelopers.com:3000/streetstrider/streetstrider3i.html 
Select the blue swatch and add the product to cart then see the image in cart and checkout and even in minicart the issue comes @AdityaShah